# Visualizing decision jungle in Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: decision-tree, azure-machine-learning-service, information-gain

I have trained a decision jungle model on Azure Machine Learning, and  now I want to visualize the trees, to see if I can identify the root nodes that are the most determinant in the decision.

When I right-click and click Visualize on the Train Model, what is shown is the parameter set used for the training. How can I either visualize the jungle, or identify the features with highest information gain from this?

Thanks in advance!